# How to set up multiple schedulers for airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have recently shifted to airflow 2.0. I wanted to understand the procedure to set up multiple schedulers. I tried to see various sources including the procedure which uses astronomer cli. But we are not using that. For other sources including airflow documentation, while they have mentioned that it is possible to do so and given some details about the database requirements, they have not given any details on how exactly one goes about setting multiple schedulers (like steps or commands).
Do we just schedule a new scheduler using

`airflow scheduler` ?
or do we have to configure something in airflow.cfg or the docker file?
Also how do we verrify that a new scheduler has been set up? Using astronomer cli, it is possible to easily kill the scheduler. But I was not able to find anything when we are not using it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you are using Helm Chart, you can use replicas for scheduler to `2`.

If you are using just VM: both the VMs can run multiple scheduler process just by running `airflow scheduler`. No additional configurations are required.

You can verify in that Airflow Webserver by going to `Browse -> Jobs` page and filter by `JobType` as `SchedulerJob` that are in state `running`.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see them running. How do you stop a scheduler? I could find some answers on StackOverflow itself. But they are not working for me.

Comment: It depends on how you started it and your deployment method, you can just press Ctrl+C

Comment: @kaxil I'm assuming the tasks running with **JobType** as **LocalTaskJob** mean that the schedulers are not properly configured. Is that right?

Comment: JobType LocalTaskJob is a different type: it LocalTaskJob is used to run task on the worker.

Comment: @kaxil I have created a separate question about stopping the airflow scheduler. Please have a look at it and let me know if you can help out.
link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685112/stopping-airflow-scheduler

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it helped you for future users

Comment: @kaxil I have installed Airflow 2.2.3 on a single VM. So, If I run airflow scheduler command twice, then two scheduler instances are running?