# Airflow, setup more than one scheduler on docker compose yaml

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm running Airflow 2.2.5 using docker compose setup. I use celery executor and 10+ worker nodes on different machines. This setup works fine for few worker nodes, but if I launch all 12 nodes, the worker instances start to crash. I suspect, that the reason might be that scheduler can't handle the traffic from all the worker nodes.

I would like to test a setup where I have multiple schedulers on the main node to see if this solves my problem. I was unable to find an answer on how to implement this sort of setup on my docker compose file. Can I just make two services scheduler1 and scheduler2 with identical definitions or is there a better way?

The official documentation was bit short on this one:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/scheduler.html?highlight=scheduler#running-more-than-one-scheduler

I know that in the Kubernetes setup the scheduler count is just one parameter, but unfortunately I do not have Kubernetes at hand at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from this post. It didn't solve the celery issue though. [How to set up multiple schedulers for airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638211/how-to-set-up-multiple-schedulers-for-airflow)